# What is the range of valid dates for the datetime module?

Tags: python, date, datetime, calendar

I'm playing with the Python [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) module. I'm using it to determine the day of the week for a given date. Python conveniently raises a `ValueError` when the date is invalid; e.g., for February 29 on non-leap years.

I have found that for years greater than 10,000 AD, `ValueError` exceptions are raised for many dates that are not February 29. This leads me to consider that the `datetime` module is not valid for dates that far in the future.

**What is the range of valid dates for the `datetime` module?**

Comment: Did you read the page you link to? *"`MAXYEAR` is 9999."*

Comment: @jonrsharpe No I didn't see that. Sorry.

Answer (score 5):

Check [`date.min`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.min) and [`date.max`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.max):

```
>>> from datetime import date
>>> date.min
datetime.date(1, 1, 1)
>>> date.max
datetime.date(9999, 12, 31)
```