# Problems getting two columns into datetime.datetime format

Tags: pandas, timestamp, datetime-format

I have code at the moment written to change two columns of my dataframe from strings into datetime.datetime objects similar to the following:

```
def converter(date):
    date = dt.strptime(date, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S')
    return date

df = pd.DataFrame({'A':['12/31/9999 0:00:00','1/1/2018 0:00:00'],
                   'B':['4/1/2015 0:00:00','11/1/2014 0:00:00']})

df['A'] = df['A'].apply(converter)
df['B'] = df['B'].apply(converter)
```

When I run this code and print the dataframe, it comes out like this

```
                     A          B
0  9999-12-31 00:00:00 2015-04-01
1  2018-01-01 00:00:00 2014-11-01
```

When I checked the data types of each column, they read

```
A            object
B    datetime64[ns]
```

But when I check the format of the actual cells of the first row, they read

```
<class 'datetime.datetime'>
<class 'pandas._libs.tslib.Timestamp'>
```

After experimenting around, I think I've run into an out of bounds error because of the date '12/31/9999 0:00:00' in column 'A' and this is causing this column to be cast as a datetime.datetime object. My question is how I can also convert column 'B' of my dataframe to a datetime.datetime object so that I can run a query on the columns similar to

```
df.query('A > B')
```

without getting an error or the wrong output.

Thanks in advance

Comment: relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/q/39491327/6671176

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `'9999'` is just some dummy year, you can simplify your life by choosing a dummy year which is in bounds (or one that makes more sense given your actual data):

```
import pandas as pd

df.replace('9999', '2060', regex=True).apply(pd.to_datetime)
```

#### Output:

```
           A          B
0 2060-12-31 2015-04-01
1 2018-01-01 2014-11-01

A    datetime64[ns]
B    datetime64[ns]
dtype: object
```

---

As @coldspeed points out, it's perhaps better to remove those bad dates:

```
df.apply(pd.to_datetime, errors='coerce')
#           A          B
#0        NaT 2015-04-01
#1 2018-01-01 2014-11-01
```

Comment: I don't think this is as good as just having the date be NaN.

Comment: @coldspeed I think the `NaT` is appropriate in most cases. Though in some real cases (say A and B are start and stop dates for some enrollment, and '9999' is just a dummy year used to indicate the person is still enrolled on the day of the data extract), then I think the replace with a *sensible* real date (perhaps the year of the data pull in that example) is more appropriate, since with `NaT` you lose the fact that `9999-12-31 > 2015-04-01`

Comment: Thank you for the help! It worked great, I just filled the null values in with the very large dates and got the result I wanted